# why performance is zero for the following logic?

Tags: python, performance-testing, correctness

I wrote this function for codility and got 0 in performance and 100% for correctness.

```
A = [-1, -3]
B = [1,2,3]
C = [1,4,5,6,77,2]
```

The function below is supposed to return smallest integer but not present int list passed to it.

```
def solution(A):
    temp = 0;
    tempLst = []
    for item in A:
        temp = temp+1
        if temp not in A:
            tempLst.append(temp)

    return min(tempLst) if tempLst else max(A) + 1
```

why is it so ? All I wanted is to do it without heap, itertools , partial .

Comment: What is the code supposed to be doing in plain english?

Comment: Hello @JacobIRR , my bad I have added what the function is supposed to be doing .

Comment: Eh, I still don't know what you mean by "but not present int list passed to it". The results I get for A, B, C are 1, 4, 3. It sounds like it's looking for the smallest whole number not in the list?

Comment: Sounds more like it's trying to find the smallest positive integer that is not in the list.

Answer (score -1):

You have what is effectively a nested loop.

```
for item in A:
```

This line loops over all elements of `A`.

```
    if temp not in A:
```

... and for each of those elements you loop again, comparing `temp` to each element of `A`.

The runtime of this code is quadratic in the size of `A`. E.g. if `A` has 1000 elements, this code takes 1000*1000 = 1,000,000 steps to finish.

Comment: I can iterate over xrange(min(A), max(A)) , and check every incremented value present in A, is there any other possible way?